# Where to redirect new users needing advice with formatting?

Tags: discussion, help-center

While doing first post reviews, I sometimes find that the user didn't learn to use the toolbar just above the text field they write to. I didn't find any better help topic than those [on editting](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/editing) and [on Markdown/HTML formatting](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), but these tools are not explained there (doing the same by code might suffice for programmers on SO, but not for us). There is [a similar question on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25079/202747), but it focused on code formatting and the answers didn't link to any useful source.

What to do? I usually just say that there's such a toolbar, but I don't know a good source to link and whole manual is too long for a comment.

Comment: I have asked for creating a help topic for absolute basics of editing on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213106/202747. If there already is something like that, I expect to get a link for it in an answer. If I get some answer for this question there, I'll forward it here ASAP.

Comment: So the community on meta.SO is generally inimical to the idea of having such a resource :-(

Comment: You could write up your own guide here on meta, if you want.

Comment: I hesitate whether to do it or not. 3 upvotes right now is a mild signal we want it, but I don't have time to do it myself now. I'll see in the first half of January; if the upvoting will continue and anyone else won't write this, I'll make it myself.